# How to escape a string to insert into MySQL via PDO *without* using prepared statements (legacy app)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know that prepared statements are the way to go, but I have a large legacy application that I'm converting across.

I've changed it from mysqli to PDO as the first step, and will now be converting all the queries in it to prepared statements.  But there's hundreds of them, so that will take time.

In the interim, what function should I be using to escape strings?

I tried `$PDO->quote`, but it appears to do 2 things:

1) surround a string with quotes
2) convert ' in the string to \'

I can trim the start/finish quote off easily enough, but I then end up with \' being inserted into the database.  I think the correct escaping would be to convert ' to '', so I'm not sure why it's doing a backslash instead?

I KNOW this is horrific, but this is the kludge I've come up with in the meantime...

```
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);
$s = str_replace("''","'",$s);

$s = str_replace("'","''",$s);
```

What should I be doing instead?  And again, this is as a stopgap while I convert everything over to prepared statements.

---

This is how the app used to do it, mysqli-style:

```
function SQLSafe($s) {
    global $DB;
    $s = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($s) : $s;
    $s = $DB->escape_string($s);
    return $s;
}
```

where $DB is

```
$DB = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$DB->set_charset('utf8');
$DB->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

and used like:

```
$DB->query("INSERT INTO USERS (username) VALUES ('" . SQLSafe($username) . "')");
```

Comment: add slashes like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: `quote()` should work. I suspect your problem is not the app being old, the problem is the app has being doing it incorrectly from the beginning. You should share a minimal self-contained example of the **original code** you need to replace so we can find out how it's misusing `mysqli_real_escape_string()` exactly.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I now realise that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` does not surround the string in quotes while `PDO::quote()` does. Still, the rest should be similar so original code is still welcome.

Comment: @Galvani I wouldn't recommend `addslashes()` since it knows nothing about MySQL or character encodings. It's a horrible function that should have never been written.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've added some a sample of the original code above.

Comment: I've answered the question myself now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `PDO::quote()` behave similarly in MySQL context—the only difference is that the former does not add surrounding quotes, so you use it this way:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name
    FROM user
    WHERE email='$email'";
```

... and the latter does add them so you use it this way:

```
$email = $pdo->quote(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name
    FROM user
    WHERE email=$email";
```

If there're too many queries to get SQL fixed, I suggest you write a custom wrapper function and search+replace `mysqli_real_escape_string` calls with it, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Emulates mysqli_real_escape_string()
 * 
 * @param PDO $pdo
 * @param mixed $input
 * @return string Escaped input, not surrounded in quotes 
 */
function pdo_real_escape_string (PDO $pdo, $input) {
    $output = $pdo->quote($input);
    return $output[0] === "'"
        ? mb_substr($output, 1, -1, 'utf-8' /* or whatever */)
        : $output;
}
```

Beware that **this is an ugly hack** and **prepared statements are the only sensible method**. For instance, `null` values will become empty strings (`''`). It's only meant as temporary replacement for a similarly ugly hack.

It's also worth nothing that `PDO::quote()` is implemented (or not) by each database driver. That means that the driver author can choose how to interpret this part of the documentation:

> `PDO::quote()` places **quotes around the input string (if required)**
>   and escapes special characters within the input string, using a
>   quoting style appropriate to the underlying driver.

Some quick testing suggests that the MySQL driver always add such quotes but YMMV.

Comment: Sorry, but that's absolutely pointless approach that is addressing an artificial issue and can't be of any help for the real life. A better suggestion would be a wrapper for PDO that could help with the transition.

Comment: Also, your first code sample needs to pass a link to `mysqli_real_escape_string`, since you're using the procedural style.

Comment: @Codemonkey Fixed, thank you. Although mysqli code was there for mere illustration purposes, being correct is never too much to ask for ;-)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'd say it's at most a matter of opinion. I'm a fan of gradual rewrites (they add value quickly, problems arise progressively and are easy to detect and fix...). Full rewrites look awesome on paper but in practice they often mean that the project stalls for years and you eventually end up with a half-baked codebase that annoys users with lots of cosmetic changes and often misses some of the original features. I maintain legacy code myself and it's of little help when you ask for a tiny detail about ODBC and get "dump all the code" in return.

Answer (score 1):

I can see now that the problem I had was just that I was passing a string through `SQLSafe` twice by mistake.  So `O'Hare` was becoming first `O\'Hare`, but then `O\\\'Hare`.  That's why I was ending up with backslashes in the database, it was my mistake and nothing wrong with the PDO->quote function I was using.

So the function is now simply:

```
function SQLSafe($s) {
    global $PDO;

    return substr($PDO->quote($s), 1, -1);
}
```

(I removed the line about `get_magic_quotes_gpc` as it always returns FALSE since php5.4)

---

OK, after comment about numerical data, I've changed it to

```
function SQLSafe(string $s): string
{
    global $PDO;
    $s = $PDO->quote($s);
    if ($s[0] === "'") {
        $s = substr($s, 1, -1);
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: The [`PDO::quote()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) suggests it doesn't always add quotes but I couldn't make it *not* add them. I didn't dig further but suspect it might be one of those driver configuration subtleties. Just ensure you don't end up with corrupted numeric data.

Comment: The worst part that this is a public site ans some unsuspecting user may come up and they would likely get an impression that such a function makes whatever SQL "safe".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it couldn't make it not adding quotes because it will make this function essentially pointless and dangerous.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Do you have an example where injecting a numeric PHP variable into a string will result in SQL injection? It's a concern I've heard about several times but I couldn't figure out the details.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it's no rocket science. $SQL="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".escape_without_quotes($allegedly_numeric_variable)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry, I meant in a context like `function SQLSafe($input){ if ( is_int($input) )`...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález well, this kind of condition just makes no sense. If a variable is already of the int type, it will do no harm anyway. The harm is coming from the fact that from inside of such a function you just cannot tell whether there are quotes in the query or not.

Comment: For my use case it's fine, I only ever use it inside of a pair of single quotes in my strings.  I know mistakes can happen, yada yada, but for this transitional period it's perfectly adequate for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to answer the real problem you face, not an XY one you stumbled upon because of taking the wrong turn.

If you are indeed converting from *mysqli*, not mysql ext, then you can keep with mysqli and use this extension's built-in prepared statements. Just make sure that `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` method exists in your system.

In case it is not mysqli but mysql ext-based code you are actually rewriting, then I see no point in a gradual rewriting you are aiming to. Just sit and rewrite everyting to PDO prepared statements. **You have to rewrite all your code anyway**, even with this strange approach of yours with stripping quotes from PDO's quote. Why do the same job twice?

Comment: It is mysqli, not mysql.  The main reason I switched over to PDO in the first place was because I'm a fan of PHP7s strict typing feature, and PDO returns ints/strings appropriately whereas mysqli always returns strings, so I don't think I can be persuaded to go back to mysqli?

Comment: @Codemonkey it is interesting phenomenon that you are obsessed with PHP7 features yet deliberately wants to make your code PHP3-style with manual escaping.  And of course mysqli returns you typed results as well as PDO does.

Comment: It feels like you've not read my initial question, I'm just trying to modernise an old codebase, I can't see why this would be a bad thing.

Comment: I can't do it all overnight, so I'm doing it bit by bit.  Better than not doing it at all.

Comment: @Codemonkey this is a strangest thing of them all. Given you have 10 queries with string input. Instead of converting them once each, for some reason you want to convert the same code twice - first time adding escaping and second time removing escaping. Surely it's better than not doing at all but I fail to see any benefit of the double job. I rather suspect that you plan to keep with your half-butt escaping solution. That won't give your strictly typed result BTW, as you can get it out of a prepared statement only.

Comment: All I wanted to do was to change the SQLsafe function to escape its inputs using a PDO link so I didn't have to open a mysqli link just for the  `escape_string` method.  There's no "double work".  This is very minimal work to switch the codebase entirely from mysqli to PDO.  The heavy lifting will come in when I start to rewrite all the php code that generates the mysql queries to use PDO parameterization, which is next on the list.  Today's step can be completed site-wide easily, the parameterization will need to be done on a query-by-query basis.

Comment: @Codemonkey ok, I see now the addition you made to the question. It makes sense I have to admit. But still I hate when I see pdo::quote() stripped of surrounding quotes which diminishes this sane function to a state of old addslashes thing. But well, at least it won't make things worse than they are at the moment.